# High TG or Aluminum for LED PCB?

Tags: led, pcb-design

I've been typically using a single layer aluminum PCB for 2 x 10W LED, which helps with dissappation. Wondering if I could get away with using a high TG 170 instead? Why - get rid of jumpers. Assuming this would negatively impact the LED chips due to heat build up, unless I did some multilayer copper with heat sink on back side.

Comment: This really depends on the details of your LEDs (size, thermal dissipation, thermal pad, etc). The manufacturer will usually give you a good idea what they think is required in their documents.

Answer (score 1):

Tg refers to the [glass transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_transition) temperature of the material, **not** its thermal conductivity or ability to conduct and dissipate thermal energy. High Tg dielectrics are used to *withstand* high temperatures, rather than to help dissipate heat to *avoid* high temperatures.

Tg170 boards typically have a thermal conductivity of around 0.3-0.4W/mK, whereas typical aluminium PCBs are more like 1-3W/mK. As such, swapping from aluminium to a Tg170 board would be a pretty major downgrade in thermal conductivity, so your LEDs would almost certainly get a fair bit hotter. Thermal vias will help, but 20W is quite a lot to dissipate.

The problem here is that your LEDs are almost certainly not rated to run at 170°C. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if they were rated for less than 130°C operation, which is the Tg for basic cheap FR-4 PCBs.

Comment: Good info, thank you.